# the meaning of Time_step in Time series Data

Tags: deep-learning

I have an application that can generate 50 data in 1 second,which means the sampling_rate of my application is 50Hz. then theb data type is timeseries. then I make my data like below before training.

```
steps= 50
inp = []
out = []
for i in range(len(data_scaled_out) - (steps)):
    inp.append(data_scaled_in[i:i+steps])
    out.append(data_scaled_out[i+steps])
```

inp data shape is (50,89)

if I use data shape (50,89) is it the same I change the model's sampling rate to 1Hz? means that the model can only predict 1 data in 1 second? because my professor said that if I use the input shape (50.89) it is the same as me downsampling the frequency. Is that true?

Comment: Could you please clarify which variable has the shape (50, 89), and what are the shapes/sizes of the other variables?

Comment: I have edit the question

Comment: And what are the shapes/sizes of your other variables - data_scaled_in, data_scaled_out, and out?